# Order of integration-Triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

How can I write the triple integral $$\int_0^u\int_0^z\int_0^vf(x,y)dxdydz$$ in the form
$$\int\int\int f(x,y)dzdxdy.$$

I stuck to draw the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the integral region in the $yz$-plane is a triangle with vertexes at $(0,0)$, $(0,u)$ and $(u,u)$. Therefore,

$$\int_0^u\int_0^z\int_0^vf(x,y)dxdydz=\int_0^u\int_0^v\int_y^u f(x,y)dzdxdy.$$

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times, this task becomes way easier when you draw the graph. At first, drawing it seems impossible, but you will turn out to be better as more draws as you do. Take a look at Quanto's answer.